Access to XMLHttpRequest blocked by CORS policy:'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' In FLASK
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:5000/signincheck' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
SignIn.js:44 

I know a lot of people have gotten into this and I happen to be stuck on it too at 2am. After 4 hours of digging i found a extremely simple solution for my situation. Im using flask as my backend, mongodb as my database and react as my frontend. i used a run.py to collection all my other modules for my backend and run from one .py file. i used flask blueprint to accomplish this all I was missing is
app.secret_key = b'_5#2yL"F4Q8z\n\xec]/'

that is to be included in my main module run.py as well as CORS(app)

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
